# Allow another developer to work on my XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning

I have an XCode project I am working on, and I need to grant access to another developer to work on the project as well.  In order to do this, I believe I have to send over my private key and provisioning profile  (is this correct?)

However, I've been working on my project using my own personal iOS development certificate.  And I don't feel completely comfortable sending over all my signing identity to someone else.

What is the simplest and securest way to get the other developer working on the same project as me, without giving him access to my entire iOS dev account.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a versioning system (SVN/GIT) and let the other developer use his own provisioning profile ...

Comment: @Thor - that should be an answer :)

Comment: Thanks guys!  I'm going to get that all set up early next week. Thanks so much.  One quick question:  If the other developer isn't going to be making any changes (i.e. he literally just wants to debug the code when it's running on a device) can he do that using his own provisioning profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Atlassian Rocks!

[Go to this website](https://bitbucket.org/) create a repo, set up everything from your side. Ask the other partner to download the repo and start coding. Fight with each other when you get merge conflicts :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  One question:  the other dev isn't going to be making any changes to the project.  He just needs to run the code on his device and debug it.  Can he do that with his own provisioning profile or does he need mine?

Comment: In order to test, I guess you just need to add the device and you might need provision certificate too! Well as far as I kno, In my university we have been allocated provision certificates and they got our device id to setup. the second I worked in a company and my senior developer just added me as a developer in the main certificate and I use to test and code the application. Have you read developer faq section? you might get answer there :)

Comment: OK thanks a lot.  I think he's up and running now, just by using his own provisioning, so that will do until I set up a code repo.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can just send the project files, so s/he can work on project. Just cant test it on device if s/he doesnt have license. I dont think "Developer license" have access to add person to developer team.